# Which language to learn for Qt development?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am new to programming. I have some Knowledge Of C++ and have learned Python.

Now i want to develop a Qt Gui Application. Which language should i use for Qt development C++ or Python with PyQt. I found Python to be easy language.

Comment: A wonderful question with an awesome answer. If not StackOverflow, where do we ask these questions?

Comment: @PaulKnopf Possibly Quora, Reddit, or Hacker News

Answer (score 15):

There is no definite answer to this question. With that said...

### Pros and cons you often hear

- Python is easy, C++ is hard (in
  comparison to Python)
- C++ is fast, Python is slow (so to
  speak) performance wise.

### In reality...

Both arguments can be true or false, you can make slow C++ program, but you can also make fast Python program, you could also say C++ is not that hard if you know it really good etc.

Qt is written in C++ so the documentation examples are in C++. This is not really a problem since it is easy to port this to Python. Although I've found that for example animations with state machine cause segmentation faults with PyQt and PySide is not all that stable yet.

### So which one to pick?

Depends on your skill and assignment. If it is work you are doing go with what you know best and asses how much speed you actually need, not every app has a need for lower level code.

If you know Python, you could start building your prototype in Python, then port to C++ parts that you deemed slow and bind them back to the Python (using SIP for example) or even port the whole application to C++. This approach also makes good exercise.

But even if you wrote your whole app in Python I doubt you and your clients would ever notice the "slowness" or "fastness" if you go with C++. These things usually depend on skill of a programmer.

### Conclusion

It's entirely up to you to choose what are you are most comfortable with and to understand what your app really needs, but both languages will do the job in most cases.

My subjective advice would be to go with Python and port to C++ if you really need to. Sole reason for this advice is that you do not need to type as much in Python as you do in C++ but this can also be seen as a silly reason.

Comment: thanks for the support going to learn PyQt from tomorrow

Comment: As my answer got mutilated with down votes, I've updated it to be precise and concise. Read it if you want.

Answer (score 7):

I just finished a reasonably large project with PyQT... I think your choice should depend on three factors:

1. How big is your audience (less
   than 100 installations? More?)
2. How much functionality do you need?
   (Databases + graphics + plotting +
   signal analysis + network access +
   blah blah blah)?
3. How rapidly do
   you need to develop, both now and in
   the future?

C++/QT is great for 1) Big audience, 2) Low to medium functionality, and 3) Slow to medium development speed. Of course, you can do *anything* with C++ given enough time and money.

Python/PyQt is great for 1) Small Audience, 2) Any level (including high) functionality, and 3) Medium to fast development speed.

The benefits of Python/PyQt are that:

- you needn't worry too much about datatypes, header files, and numerous other headaches that slow development, and you get to work in a world-class interpreted environment known for its ability to foster fast and robust development.
- you can pull in massive 3rd party libraries like matplotlib, scipy, sqlalchemy, and configobj that can make complex tasks stupidly easy.

The downsides of Python/PyQt, IMHO, are that:

- it may have slower performance in some applications (who cares? How often does that really matter?)
- it may be substantially harder to deploy. Py2exe requires quite a bit of tweaking to get 3rd party libraries to work, and then you still need to build an installer and get that working. Then, every time someone installs your app you might have 10 to 100MB of unnecessary dependencies built into the thing.

Personally, I work in an engineering R&D environment where fast turnaround and extensive data analysis/visualization is key, and deployment is often to only a few dozen (tech-savvy) people. Python/Pyqt is the *clear* choice. But, if I were to be developing a simple, widely-deployed application like a bittorrent client or something, I'd go C++ all the way.

Other notes:

- PySide (a free LGPL alternative to PyQt) is rapidly progressing and seems sure to blow PyQt out of the water; I'm planning to switch within the next few months but as of now some 3rd party libraries still aren't set up for it.
- The documentation for Pyside is *much* better than for PyQt; if you need help on, say, "QListView", just search google for "Pyside QListView".
- I'd recommend only using PyQt where you need to. E.g., don't mess with QtSQL (debugging is a nightmare) when you could just use SqlAlchemy, and don't screw with Qt's configuration system when you can use the awesome library ConfigObj.
- The clear way to install Python/Pyqt/etc is using the distribution [Python(x,y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) ...  it includes, among other things: Python, PyQt, Qt, Eclipse, PyDev, QtDesigner, Spyder, iPython, and many dozens of useful scientific and computing libraries. Compiling and installing this stuff on your own is not fun.

Comment: is pyside syntax or usability is same as of PyQt  ?

Comment: Syntax: PySide is very similar to the API2 of PyQt. That is the API that is used by PyQt under Python3... *not* under Python2.x.

So, the big difference is that there are no QStrings, QVariants, etc... it's all done with Python Types. Probably bad for porting back to C++, but *great* for actually writing code in Python.

The differences are small, and for the most part natural.

The biggest usability obstacle for me is using 3rd party libraries... e.g., matplotlib requires pyqt, and isn't fooled by an import hook that substitutes Pyside for PyQt.

But, in my mind, Pyside is the future.

Comment: +1 for PySide notes, API [differences](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Differences_Between_PySide_and_PyQt) are quite small with LGPL licence. PySide FTW.

Comment: PySide doesn't support Qt5

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the arguments given by rebus, I would add that the development and maintenance time in Python is considered to be about 2-10 times faster than in C++ (in papers by [Prechelt](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/~prechelt/Biblio/jccpprt2_advances2003.pdf) and [Ousterhout](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/scripting.html)).  This is another significant advantage of Python, that you might want to consider.

Comment: +1 Maintenance is indeed very important factor to consider specially for large projects.

Answer (score 1):

My main reasons for choosing Python and PyQt4 are:

- **Readability**: I can't think in C++. I truthfully cannot. Python, on the other hand, is pretty close to English, so I find it easier to skim and debug.
- **Speed**: I find that Qt4 works almost identically in both C++ and Python when you're using it for simple applications that do little work on the inside. I coded a [book binding application](http://blender3d.github.com/Bindery/) with Python, and since it is basically a frontend to bunch of CLI tools, there is no noticeable performance lag.
- **Rapid Development**: If you can write it in words, you can probably write it in Python. When I had to implement a new feature in my program, I just opened up the source folder (which consists of only a few files. Compare *that* to C++'s header mayhem), and added it in. Sure I had to tweak it to work faster later on, but my main point is that because the language is readable, it is easy to code in, and hence increases productivity.

But just to weigh both sides equally, here's what I don't like about Python and Qt4:

- **Example Code**: Good luck trying to find some sample PyQt4 applications. The community is pretty small compared to the C++ Qt community, so don't expect tons and tons of examples.
- **IDE**: I code with [Gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/screenshots.html), so this was not a big issue for me, but it did take some hacking while I was designing the GUI. You have to trick Qt Designer into promoting your widgets in Python-compatible ways (like proving fake header file names so that the modules import properly), and other things like that. Nothing to serious. My regret was the inability to use [Qt Creator IDE](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/). It's basically a GUI designer on steroids, but it looks nice and is like Visual Studio for Qt.
- **Speed**: If your application does some serious heavy lifting, I'd stick with C++. Python is good for algorithmic things, but for raw number-crunching power, C++ is the winner.
- **Deployment**: To compile Python applications into binaries, you need to do some magical stuff with [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), [Py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), and [Py2App](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html). It's a pretty painful process (for me at least), but it's the price you pay for an interpreted language. C++ just compiles and is ready to go.

I hope this helps in your decision. Good luck!

Comment: But still Qt in standard is in C++ so is there any pros or any cons of using Qt on python over Qt/c++

Comment: No, not really. I find them to be identical in terms of functionality. I just find Python itself easier to work with than C++, so that makes Qt easier to work with. I'd stick with whatever language you are most comfortable with.

Comment: +1, gives a broader overview of the development process.

Answer (score -1):

Learn C++.  C++ executes faster than Python, and the fact that Qt is not native to Python will also slow things down slightly.  Also, there is at this point far more 3rd party software in C/C++ than in Python.  You might not need it now but down the road you might want to link to some of this.

EDIT: Looking a little harder I see that EOL is right, there is a lot of Python support for major libraries, though not for everything as lunayorn points out.  Nonetheless in all these cases the Python user is reliant on bindings, which by their nature may lag the library developments and add extra possibility for bugs.

And since I don't yet have the cred to respond to others' posts, let me say here that rebus' claim that it's all programmer relative and C++ or Python can be just as fast is completely (and dangerously, where speed is important!) wrong.  Python's ease of use comes at an unavoidable performance cost, see the wikipedia entries on interpreted vs. directly executed languages.  I know from direct experience that Matlab, which is interpreted in the way Python is, executes line for line 2 full orders of magnitude more slowly than C++.  Python and Matlab are best considered as (and in the case of Matlab at least, originally intended as) interfaces to libraries coded in languages like C or Fortran.  For serious, large programs where performance matters use C++.

Comment: could you elaborate on the "there is at this point far more 3rd party software in C/C++ than in Python" part?  As of today, the official Python Package Index (http://pypi.python.org/pypi) has 13k+ packages.  Furthermore, its standard library covers an amazing range of areas.  So, why does C++ have "far more 3rd party software"? :)

Comment: @EOL:  I guess, he's referring to 3rd party libraries atop of Qt.  There are many Qt-based libraries covering different areas, and only few of them have Python bindings available.  Actually I only now of PyQwt (binding to Qwt), whereas other libraries like QCA are not available for Python.

Comment: First of speed is relative, second of I never said (at least I think) that the two can be just as fast, but rather that you can write slow C++ code if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: What do you mean by relative?  Do you agree that a (well-written) C++ program, ported directly to Python, will execute much, much faster than its Python counterpart?

Comment: How fast can a button click be? It would probably conserve much more RAM for one thing. For most of the trivial stuff the application will be doing, the performance gain will be negligible simply because you will not be able to notice it with your naked eye. On the other hand, number crunching part of some application could be easily ported to C++ and would probably yield more performance gain supposing the right algorithms have been used. Knowing the language enough to avoid pitfalls is good for performance.